# Using Naive Bayes for sentiment classification in Perl

Tags: perl, machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

I'm experimenting around with sentiment classification for a web crawler I'm writing (don't ask me about reinventing the wheel, at least as far as the crawler is concerned!). I am currently looking into using Naive Bayes, mainly because a perl module exists to make it easier. I am, however, having a bit of a problem setting up a test case to determine good/bad movie reviews.

As I understand it, I first need to come up with a set of test data for which the module will train with. I went to a few websites that review movies, downloaded a dozen bad reviews and a dozen good reviews. I read in each file to generate a word list, then convert that into a hash of the word frequencies. Then I do the same processing for a bunch of "unknown" reviews (although I know more or less the sentiment) but I'm running into problems and I'm not sure if I'm going about this the wrong way!

Here is the testing output:

```
*** Processing good reviews
Reading set/good/anniehall.txt
Reading set/good/biglebowski.txt
Reading set/good/contact.txt
Reading set/good/eternalsunshine.txt
Reading set/good/harakiri.txt
Reading set/good/killing.txt
Reading set/good/lincoln.txt
Reading set/good/mulhollanddr.txt
Reading set/good/narayama.txt
Reading set/good/scarface.txt
Reading set/good/seven.txt
Reading set/good/shoah.txt
Reading set/good/spiritedaway.txt
*** Processing bad reviews
Reading set/bad/battlefieldearth.txt
Reading set/bad/charliesangels.txt
Reading set/bad/deathsmootchy.txt
Reading set/bad/deucebigaloweuro.txt
Reading set/bad/freddyfingered.txt
Reading set/bad/humancentipede.txt
Reading set/bad/jasonx.txt
Reading set/bad/north.txt
Reading set/bad/pootietang.txt
Reading set/bad/residentevilapocalypse.txt
Reading set/bad/savingsilverman.txt
Reading set/bad/slackers.txt
Reading set/bad/texaschainsaw.txt
*** Predicting unknown reviews
set/unknown/benjaminbutton.txt: $VAR1 = {
          'bad' => '1.06973342245912e-68',
          'good' => '1'
        };
set/unknown/epic.txt: $VAR1 = {
          'good' => '1',
          'bad' => '7.2271232924459e-35'
        };
set/unknown/hangoverpart3.txt: $VAR1 = {
          'good' => '1',
          'bad' => '1.08569835047604e-17'
        };
set/unknown/jacobsladder.txt: $VAR1 = {
          'good' => '1',
          'bad' => '9.31582505503138e-60'
        };
set/unknown/marleyme.txt: $VAR1 = {
          'good' => '1',
          'bad' => '5.57603799052706e-26'
        };
set/unknown/quantumofsolace.txt: $VAR1 = {
          'bad' => '2.40424666202666e-27',
          'good' => '1'
        };
set/unknown/thespirit.txt: $VAR1 = {
          'bad' => '2.47177895177767e-19',
          'good' => '1'
        };
set/unknown/twilight.txt: $VAR1 = {
          'good' => '1',
          'bad' => '9.77187340648713e-62'
        };
```

It seems like it invariably will mark unknown data as "good"!

This is the program itself:

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Data::Dumper;

BEGIN { push @INC, "../lib"; }
use Algorithm::NaiveBayes;

my $nb = Algorithm::NaiveBayes->new;

# For each file in each directory, retrieve a hash with each key being a
# unique word, and each value the associated frequency of that word.

# Start with scanning good reviews directory
say "*** Processing good reviews";
my @files = <set/good/*>;
foreach (@files) {
    next if ($_ =~ m/^\./); # ignore files beginning with .
    say "Reading $_";
    my %attr = hash_file($_);
    $nb->add_instance ( attributes => \%attr, label => 'good');
}

# Then scan bad reviews
say "*** Processing bad reviews";
@files = <set/bad/*>;
foreach (@files) {
    next if ($_ =~ m/^\./); # ignore files beginning with .
    say "Reading $_";
    my %attr = hash_file($_);
    $nb->add_instance ( attributes => \%attr, label => 'bad');
}

# Train, and cross fingers
$nb->train;

# Test unknown reviews
say "*** Predicting unknown reviews";
@files = <set/unknown/*>;
foreach (@files) {
    next if ($_ =~ m/^\./); # ignore files beginning with .
    print "$_: ";
    my %attr = hash_file($_);
    my $result = $nb->predict(attributes => \%attr);
    print Dumper($result);
}


# Subroutine that takes a file path and returns a hash of the word frequencies
sub hash_file {
    my ($file) = @_;
    my %words;

    my @word_list;
    open FILE, $file or die $!;
    while(<FILE>){
        chomp;
        push @word_list, split;
    }
    close FILE;

    foreach (@word_list){
        $_ =~ s/[[:punct:]]//g; # Remove punctuation
        next if ($_ eq '');

        # Increment frequency if word is in hash, or add to hash
        if (exists $words{$_} ){
            $words{$_}++;
        } else {
            $words{$_} = 1;
        }

    }
    return %words;
}
```

I'm hoping there are some obvious errors in that code, but I've checked the hash subroutine and it seems to be spitting out correct hashes. The only other thing I can think of is that maybe I'm not using enough data to train it? Maybe my entire approach is misguided?

Thanks for any insights

Comment: I suspect you need to filter out small words like "a", "the" otherwise it might find them

Comment: Your code does have some unidiomatic parts, but it looks quite fine overall. It should be working allright, but there is no way to verify without seeing your training data. I ran a simplified version of your code on fictional reviews, and it worked allright (I also lowercased all words).

Comment: I was wondering about "a" and "the" but I was kind of thinking that the statistical analysis would somewhat filter those out automatically, since they'd exist in somewhat the same frequency of all the data?

Comment: I've been playing around with the data sets I'm using to train the program. It seems like if I use more good data than bad, or vice versa, it skews the predictions that way. The data I'm using in the example above is skewed good because although I have the same number of good vs bad reviews, the good reviews tend to be way longer. Constructing a new test case gives me a bit better results, but I can see no practical way to prevent this...

Comment: 1. 20-30 train instances are not likely to get you far in terms of accuracy for sentiment analysis, especially with NB.
2. To somewhat mitigate the difference of corpus sizes, you can apply feature selection (e.g. using infogain) and pick the same model size for both classes.
3. if review length is an indicator to its sentiment, you may want to add it as a feature.